# Get only 3 digit and 3 digit without word although they are together with regular expression

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I am beginner in regular expression. For my case, I have an issue that alphabet and number might have space or might not have space like this.

> 4473 333hello 564 394844he hello

I need to take **333, 564**

I have tried like this and they are not okay. How shall I do?

```
print(re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', "4473 333hello 564 394844he hello")) //it give ['564']


print(re.findall(r'\w+[0-9]{3}\w+', "4473 333hello 564 394844he hello")) // it give ['39484he']
```

Comment: It give ['4473 333', '564 39484']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
(?<!\d)\d{3}(?!\d)
```

#### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R7Jbuy/1)

Details:

- `(?<!\d)` - Negative Lookbehind to make sure there is no digit just before the match
- `\d{3}` - Match 3 digits
- `(?!\d)` - Negative lookahead to make sure there is no digit just after the match.

Comment: wow. this one is very short and effective. Thanks for your your explanation too. I need that explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/s2nKi4/2)

```js
const regex = /\D\d{3}\s?/g;
const str = `4473 333hello 564 394844he hello
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. i will try.